# Slack Modal, Generic Connection Error Upon Submission

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I have a Slack app that opens a modal when someone from my team "rejects" a colleagues access request. The modal prompts the person rejecting the request to give a reason, and then the original Slack message in our channel is updated; the person who submitted the request is sent a Slack with the reasoning; the Zendesk ticket is updated with the person who rejected the request and their reasoning; and all of the events are logged in my SQL database.

All of these things happen without issue. All of them, but every single time the modal "times out" and prompts us with "We had some trouble connecting."

I'm at my wits end here. Any suggestions?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myjw2.png)

The modal should simply close as all of the dependent actions have successfully completed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.